# Ferrite Magnet as Ferrite Inductor Core?

Tags: inductor, ferrite, core

I have a toroidal “ferrite” ceramic magnet lying around and am wondering what the similarities are (if any) between one of these that has been put in the oven to remove most of its magnetization and a standard ferrite core used in inductors.

Could I make an inductor with one of these + magnet wire and if so, just *how* crap of an inductor would it be?

Comment: The characteristics of ferrites vary so widely that there's nothing useful to say, other than yes, you can wind an inductor using it. It'll probably be pretty indifferent electrically.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the right ferrite for a particular job has to be done with care and take account of: -

- the cores basic magnetic permeability
- the cores losses vs frequency
- the cores permeability change with temperature

> *Could I make an inductor with one of these + magnet wire and if so,
> just how crap of an inductor would it be?*

Yes you can make an inductor with it but, regarding how good it will be is really impossible to say. Why bother when there are tons to choose from and all of them should have data sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as I was looking into building a 30 kVA induction heater (https://www.instructables.com/30-kVA-Induction-Heater/). I have always collected speaker magnets and have a friend that owns a junkyard, so virtual unlimited supply. It looks like it may be possible, but not sure what the efficiency of it is while it has it's magnetic field.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_core

Of course, you could try using a demagnetizer...